# SALT and HASH using pbkdf2

Tags: node.js, passwords, pbkdf2, password-storage

I am using the following methods to create a salted and hashed password from the crypto lib in nodejs:

```
crypto.randomBytes(size, [callback])
crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, callback)
```

For the randomBytes call (creating the SALT) what size should I use? I have heard 128-bit salts, maybe up to 256-bit. It looks like this function uses a size in bytes so can I assume a size of 32 (256 bits) is sufficient?

For the pbkdf2 call, what is a good number of iterations and what is a good length for the key (keylen)?

Also, for storage I have seen examples of storing the salt, length, iterations and derviedkey in the same column. I am using an example which separates the 4 by `::`, i.e.:

```
salt::derivedKey::keyLength::iterations
```

Doing this, I can then separate on `::` to get the 4 values, so I can generate a derived key based on a provided password to see if it matches. Is this the correct way to store this? Or should I be a little more "deceptive" in combining these values?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**1. Random bytes size**:

Salts should be at least the same size as your hash function, so for `sha256` you should use at least 32 bytes. Node.js Crypto's `pbkdf2` uses `SHA1`, so 20 bytes should be the minimum. However, the least you should use is **64 bits (8 bytes)**, as explained in #3. (Source: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

**2. PBKDF2 number of iterations**:

See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256) for a great discussion. I took from it that **10.000 range** is sufficient without impact performance, but this is hardware/performance dependant.

**3. PBKDF2 length**:

See [this other discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31564/key-length-and-hash-function-in-pbkdf2) about key lengths. The parameter is again the hashing function used, in your case SHA-1, so 20 bytes is the correct value. Since [PBKDF2's Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) recommends salts of at least **64 bits**, it's a waste to generate keys smaller than your input, so use at least **8 bytes**. Do not use output length of greater than 20, as it provides no additional security, but doubles computation time for each multiple of 20.

**4. How to store variables**:

Discussed in all the links above (especially [the first](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)), salts should be saved along passwords (but never reused elsewhere), usually by appending it first in the resulting string (salt:hash), or in another database column.

As far as other variables, their knowledge is not critical for breaching security (as stated in [Kerckhoffs's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), so you could parametrize it safely anywhere. Your way of doing it by separating them with "::" is fine, *but you are saving extra information*. [Crackstation's codes](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) only save `"algorithm:iterations:salt:hash"`, so in your case, **`"salt::derivedKey::iterations"`** is all you need.

Comment: "Since PBKDF2's Standard recommends salts of at least 64 bits, it's a waste to generate keys smaller than your input, so use at least 64 bytes." salt input only has to be 8 bytes long (64 *bits*), is there a typo somewhere here?

Comment: @StrangeWill yes there is, see Michael`s comment. But I'm editing my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Actually, since my answer is old and already accepted, I'd rather not change it that much. But sizes in bold at #1 and #3 would change to **20 bytes** recommended - PBKDF2 recommends 64bits, so 8 bytes, but salts should be at least the same size of hash functions, so for SHA1 in case of Node.js Crypt, that would be 20 bytes, and SHA256 would be 32 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Fernando is mostly correct, but beware that #3 is mis-sourced. The recommended salt length is 64 **bits**, not bytes.

Using 64 bytes for the derived key is acceptable, but would be overkill for the salt alone.

Comment: You're right to point my mistake. My conclusion on #3 would then change to a *32 bytes* salt. The reasoning for this comes from the first sourced article:

"A good rule of thumb is to use a salt that is the same size as the output of the hash function."

So if he's using SHA-256, his salt should be the same as the output (32 bytes), which is above the recommended minimum of 64 bits.

Comment: Kinda, for example `openssl enc` command line tool generates and uses 64 bits. NIST recommends "at least 128 bits". https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf